# Use an attribute not present in the specified classobject

Tags: ldap

I'm starting out studying LDAP protocol and this is an example of a possible entry that I found while [reading](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LDAP-HOWTO/ldapbackends.html):

```
dn: o=TUDelft, c=NL
o: TUDelft
objectclass: organization
```

Now I looked for the `organization` classobject in the core.schema and I found that the only one mandatory attribute is `o` and in the attribute definition there isn't the `c` attribute:

```
objectclass ( 2.5.6.4 NAME 'organization'
    DESC 'RFC2256: an organization'
    SUP top STRUCTURAL
    MUST o
    MAY ( userPassword $ searchGuide $ seeAlso $ businessCategory $
        x121Address $ registeredAddress $ destinationIndicator $
        preferredDeliveryMethod $ telexNumber $ teletexTerminalIdentifier $
        telephoneNumber $ internationaliSDNNumber $ 
        facsimileTelephoneNumber $ street $ postOfficeBox $ postalCode $
        postalAddress $ physicalDeliveryOfficeName $ st $ l $ description ) )
```

So my question is: if an entry is defined as beloging to a sort of objectclass (in this case `organization`) can it use other attribute too?

Answer (score 0):

An LDAP entry can have any attributes that are defined for any of its objectclasses. In your example, the entry has only the one objectclass `organization`. Thus, that entry *must* have an `o` attribute (which it does) and *may* have any of the other attributes listed in the MUST section of `organization`'s schema definition. If you want the entry to have attributes *not* in `organization`'s definition, you must add another objectclass that does contain that attribute.

For example, if you add the objectclass `organizationalPerson` you can then add `organizationalPerson`'s attributes which include `street` and `postalAddress`. (Let's ignore the fact that it does not make much sense that an entry be both an organization and a person.)

You said "the attribute definition there isn't the `c` attribute". The `c=NL` in the dn `o=TUDelft, c=NL` is not an attribute, but rather, part of the entry's distinguished name.